# D&D 5e races Dragonborn and Tieflings?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, tiefling, dragonborn

I've recently started playing a play by post campaign as a player. It has occurred to me that Dragonborn Paladins are popular characters and so are a Tiefling Warlocks.What kind of challenges would I face with playing one of those race/class combo. I normally play half elf or human but would be open to try one of those . Pros and cons please. I used to play 3.5e all the time so 5th is new to me kinda

Comment: These kinds of issues tend to depend on the setting, and are mostly up to what the DM decides to do with that -- it's mostly a matter of opinion and guesswork what they'll do, if anything, hence the closure. You'd probably be best off talking to your DM.

Comment: This question would fit a [discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) better than a Q&A site.   Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get an idea of how a Q&A site differs from a discussion forum.  What problem are you trying to solve: in other words, are you the last person in your group to pick a character and you are not sure which of the two above choices is better for your group?  Do you have a specific build template or objective for your character that needs help?  Are you trying to optimize a build?

Answer (score 8):

The only "problems" with these races are that they are considered "uncommon". All this means is that you are easily identified in a crowd, due to being a 6-foot tall lizard man, or a demonic creature. For the most part, the only disadvantage you might come across is that people might be wary of you in an interaction.

As for advantages, the Dragonborn has a breath weapon, which varies depending on your ancestry, and the Tiefling has access to a range of spells as the character levels up, such as Thaumaturgy and Hellish Rebuke. In addition, Tieflings get fire resistance as a racial trait and fire damage is one of the most common elemental damages.

You can discover more by reading the PHB; all of this is covered in the book, as well as all other playable races.

Comment: It also depends greatly on how your DM's world views these races, I don't allow Dragonborn because I don't have a place for them and Tieflings are essentially the untouchables of my world or simply killed at birth in most cases. I run a rather brutal and racially segregated world though, not the traditional fluffy cosmopolitan type. So disadvantages could be what @Ben says to outright lynch mobs :)

Comment: How the races are portrayed in-game is a completely separate issue, and likely the reason why this was closed as opinion based. My description of these races comes directly from the descriptions provided in the PHB (p. 33)

Comment: I for one played a game that was nothing but uncommon races, and to make it a bit different, humans, dwarves and elves didn't exist.

Comment: Don't forget that Tieflings have resistance to fire which is *really* good.

Comment: @RobRose yes, and Dragonborn also have resistances depending on their ancestry. However, I didn't list everything off, since this is all freely available in the PHB.